# Rating React Logic

Tags: reactjs

I am following through a tutorail and I can't understand the logic behind the rating part where it will show some stars as per rating number. For instance the rating is around 4.5 the stars will be 4 and half star.

```
const Rating = ({ value, text }) => {
    return (
        <div class="flat-star style-1">
            <i className={value >=1 ? 
                'fa fa-star' : 
                value >= 0.5 
                ? 'fa fa-star-half-o' 
                : 'fa fa-star-o' 
            }></i>

         <i className={value >=2 ?  
                'fa fa-star' : 
                value >= 1.5 
                ? 'fa fa-star-half-o' 
                : 'fa fa-star-o' 
            }></i>

<i className={value >=3 ?  
                'fa fa-star' : 
                value >= 2.5 
                ? 'fa fa-star-half-o' 
                : 'fa fa-star-o' 
            }></i>

<i className={value >=4 ?  
                'fa fa-star' : 
                value >= 3.5 
                ? 'fa fa-star-half-o' 
                : 'fa fa-star-o' 
            }></i>

<i className={value >= 5 ?  
                'fa fa-star' : 
                value >= 4.5 
                ? 'fa fa-star-half-o' 
                : 'fa fa-star-o' 
            }></i>  
            
           <span>({text && text})</span>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Anyone can explain this line per line to me in layman's term? Sorry newbie here.

Comment: what tutorial is this from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have here five `i` elements each one correspond to a star and the logic goes like this:

for a given `value` we will check all the five stars starting from the first one:

```
<i className={value >=1 ? 
            'fa fa-star' : 
            value >= 0.5 
            ? 'fa fa-star-half-o' 
            : 'fa fa-star-o' 
        }></i>
```

let's analyse this first `i`:

1- if `value >= 1` then give it the className `fa fa-star` which is [full star](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icon/star).

2- else if `value` less than `1` but greater than or equal `0.5` then give it the className `fa fa-star-half-o` which is [half star](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icon/star-half-o).

so it always renders half star there is no percentage star between `0.5` and `1`.

3- else if `value` is less than `0.5` then give it className `fa fa-star-o` which is an [empty star](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icon/star-o).

so it always renders empty star there is no percentage star between `0` and `0.5`.

and so on for the all other four stars.
I hope this make sense to you.